# Moment.JS not rendering correct month on two different dates

Tags: javascript, momentjs

[MomentJS Problem Attached In This Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yFl0c.png)

I am unable to get the Month number from the dates using Moment.js, You can see that it is accepting one date but not other, showing Invalid date.

```
            var l =  moment(this.cellData[0]['"OD"'], "DD/MM/YYYY").format("DD/MM/YYYY");
            var p = moment().format("M");
            console.log(' l ', moment(l), ' p ', p);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the default moment parser parses in the following format:

`MM/DD/YYYY`

What your code is doing is the following:

```js
var l =  moment("17/09/2021", "DD/MM/YYYY").format("DD/MM/YYYY"); //outputs "17/09/2021"
moment(l) // -> passes the string "17/09/2021" but without the format

// FIX

moment(l, "DD/MM/YYY");
```

Comment: Please answer in my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/57jqbLxw/